# SwiftUI transition not working properly when it contains LazyVGrid

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-animation, lazyvgrid, swiftui-transition

I want a view to come in from the right when pressing a component. The issue is that the Vstack that contains the LazyVGrid slides into the screen after the LazyVGrid components appear (w/o a transition). The transition and animation are on the outermost component (the Vstack).

```
ZStack{
//other View
 if(showNumPad){
  AddExpenseNumPadView()//the view that contains the LazyVGrid
   .frame(maxWidth: 355)
   .background(Color.green)
   .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
   .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2.0))
}
}
```

Please help I am not sure what the issue is and I have been spending way too much on it. Thank you!

I tried changing where the transition and animation, and adding on a delay.

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that **produces your issue**, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  
`The issue is that the Vstack that contains the LazyVGrid...`, I don't see any `VStack` or `LazyVGrid` in your code, and as you say 
this is where the problem is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.